# How to create rows from a running number?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design, ruby-on-rails-3.1, data-migration

I'm trying write code of running numbers from document numbers, with the following values

Data in mind :

```
   document_types records :
       {:document_type_code => 'PR', :running_no => 2, ...}
       {:document_type_code => 'SO', :running_no => 1, ...}

   transactions records :
       {:id => 1, :document_no=> 'PR000001', :document_type_code=> 'PR', ...}
       {:id => 2, :document_no=> 'SO000001', :document_type_code=> 'SO', ...}
       {:id => 3, :document_no=> 'PR000002', :document_type_code=> 'PR', ...}
```

The design:

```
create_table :runnings do |t|
  t.string :document_type_code, :null => false, :limit => 2
  t.integer :running_no, :null => false, :default => 0
  ...
  t.timestamps
end

create_table :transactions do |t|
  t.string :document_no, :null => false
  t.string :document_type_code, :null => false, :limit => 2      
  ...
  t.timestamps
end
```

How do I generate the document_no in Transactions?

```
 document = Transaction.new
 document.document_type_code = 'PR'
 document.document_no = ??????
 ...
 document.save!
```

Comment: Does the `:id` matter or could the order be `document_no => PR00001, document_no => PR00002` as well? You could also store an integer in document_no, and make `document-no/document_type_code` a composite key.

Answer (score 2):

Use the ruby method 'next' :

```
irb(main):019:0> 'PR000001'.next
=> "PR000002"
```

Also you can use method 'succ':

```
irb(main):022:0> 'PR000001'.succ
=> "PR000002"
```

Take a look on link :

http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Ruby-on-Rails/Iterating-and-Incrementing-Strings-in-Ruby/3/

**EDITED :**

You can get incremented document no like:

```
transaction = Transaction.last 
transaction.nil? 'PR000001' ? : transaction.document_no.succ
OR
transaction.nil? 'PR000001' ? : transaction.document_no.next
```

Hope that help.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the count of all the running numbers for each 'document_type_code' and increment that from 1

you may write a scope for this

HTH